# How to show error message after exceeding maxLength in dynamic formArray?

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I have a dynamic form array, after clicking on add button I am adding dynamic fields. I am trying to use **maxLength** validation on one of the field of dynamic form. Technically it is working but if field is invalid I wanted to show error message.

I have tried below conditions to show error message:

```
    <mat-hint *ngIf="workflowAddForm.controls.runnerNodes['controls'][i].hasError('maxLength', 'script_file_content')">Max 7 characters</mat-hint>
OR
    <mat-hint *ngIf="workflowAddForm.get('runnerNodes')['controls'][i].value['script_file_content'].hasError('maxLength')">Max 7 characters</mat-hint>
OR
    <div *ngIf="script_file_content.errors?.['maxLength']">Max 7 characters</div>
```

But I am getting errors like *hasError is not a function* OR *Parser Error: Unexpected token [, expected identifier or keyword at column 29 in [script_file_content.errors?.['maxLength']]*

Below is my code

**component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="workflowAddForm" class="form-cont">
        <div class="col-lg-12 row p-0">
          <div class="form-field-cont col-lg-6">
            <mat-form-field class="col-lg-12" appearance="outline"  [floatLabel]="'always'" [hideRequiredMarker]="false">
              <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
              <input matInput  placeholder="Workflow Name" formControlName="workflow_name" required>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-12 row p-0">
          <ng-container formArrayName="runnerNodes" *ngFor="let nodes of workflowAddForm.get('runnerNodes')['controls']; let i = index;">
            <div class="col-lg-6" [formGroupName]="i">
              <div class="form-field-cont runnerFields">
                <mat-form-field class="col-lg-12" appearance="outline"  [floatLabel]="'always'" [hideRequiredMarker]="false">
                  <mat-label>Script Name</mat-label>
                  <input matInput  placeholder="sample.py" formControlName="script_name" required>
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>

              <div class="form-field-cont">
                <mat-form-field class="col-lg-12" appearance="outline"  [floatLabel]="'always'" [hideRequiredMarker]="false">
                  <mat-label>Script file content</mat-label>
                  <textarea matInput placeholder="Script file content" formControlName="script_file_content" style="height:200px" required></textarea>
                  <!-- <mat-hint *ngIf="workflowAddForm.controls.runnerNodes['controls'][i].hasError('maxLength', 'script_file_content')">Max 7 characters</mat-hint> -->
                  <!-- <mat-hint *ngIf="workflowAddForm.get('runnerNodes')['controls'][i].value['script_file_content'].hasError('maxLength')">Max 7 characters</mat-hint> -->
                  <!-- <div *ngIf="script_file_content.errors?.['maxLength']">Max 7 characters</div> -->
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>
              <div class="deleteIcon" *ngIf="i != 0">
                <i class="material-icons cursor-pointer" matTooltip="Remove" (click)="removeRunner(i)" style="color:red;">delete</i> 
              </div>
            </div>
            
          </ng-container>
          
          <div class="AddIcon" *ngIf="runnerNodeLength !== 2"> 
            <i class="material-icons cursor-pointer mt-1" matTooltip="Add Script" (click)="addMoreRunner()"  style="color: #017CAD;">add_circle_outline</i> 
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-field-cont runnerFields">
              <mat-form-field class="col-lg-12" appearance="outline"  [floatLabel]="'always'" [hideRequiredMarker]="false">
                <mat-label>Config File Name</mat-label>
                <input matInput  placeholder="config.json" formControlName="config_name">
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
            <div class="form-field-cont">
              <mat-form-field class="col-lg-12" appearance="outline"  [floatLabel]="'always'" [hideRequiredMarker]="false">
                <mat-label>Config file content</mat-label>
                <textarea matInput placeholder="Config file content" formControlName="config_file_content" style="height:200px"></textarea>
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-12 row p-0">
          <div class="form-field-cont col-lg-6">
            <mat-form-field class="col-lg-12" appearance="outline"  [floatLabel]="'always'" [hideRequiredMarker]="false">
              <mat-label>Executer Command</mat-label>
              <input matInput  placeholder="python3 filename.py" formControlName="executer_command" required>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

**component.ts**

```
    createWorkflowAddFormBuilderObj(){
    this.workflowAddForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      workflow_name: '',
      runnerNodes: this.formBuilder.array([ this.createRunnerNode() ]),
      executer_command: '',
      config_name: '',
      config_file_content: ''
    });
  }

  createRunnerNode(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      script_name: '',
      script_file_content: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(7)]]
    });
  }

  addMoreRunner(){
    this.runnerNodes = this.workflowAddForm.get('runnerNodes') as FormArray;
    this.runnerNodes.push(this.createRunnerNode());
    this.runnerNodeLength = this.runnerNodes.controls.length;
  }

  removeRunner(index){
    (this.workflowAddForm.get('runnerNodes') as FormArray).removeAt(index);
    this.runnerNodeLength = this.runnerNodes.controls.length;
  }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the implementation for `script_file_content` getter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to grab the reference to the control from the top form.
Since you are looping through the `FormArray` controls in the template:

```
<ng-container ... *ngFor="let nodes of workflowAddForm.get('runnerNodes')['controls']; ...">
```

In the `nodes` variable you already have a reference to each node `FormGroup` (consider renaming the variable to node)

From there you just need to use the `get()`method to grab the `script_file_content` control and check if it has the error.

```
<mat-hint *ngIf="nodes.get('script_file_content').hasError('maxlength')">
```

Also notice that the `maxlength` error key is all in lowercase.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you so much @akotech. I was not accessing the field correctly. The *ngIf should be like this *ngIf="workflowAddForm.get('runnerNodes')['controls'][i].controls['script_file_content'].hasError('maxlength')" but your answer looks more simple. I will use yours.

Answer (score 0):

Two silly mistakes I did

1. Not accessing the validator field properly. It should be like

`<mat-error *ngIf="workflowAddForm.get('runnerNodes')['controls'][i].controls['script_file_content'].hasError('maxlength')">Max 7 characters</mat-error>`

2. CamelCase **maxLength** inside .hasError(). It should be in small case `.hasError('maxlength')`